# JPA Enitiy with one columns joined in a relationship for two other entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Currently I'm trying to implement several entities of which one has a column in database which can represent both of other two entities.

To make it clear these are the tables I'm talking about and I can **not** change them

Images table:
[image: IMAGES table]

Users table is pretty big, but part of it should be enough:
[image: Users table]

And pages table:

[image]

the logic is that image can be owned by user or by page. who it is owned by indicates by position_id and path columns. so path can be either USER or PAGE, and position_id is user's/page's id.

How can I implement ManyToOne relation between position_id and user and page in JPA?

I imageined it would look something like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="position_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Where(clause="path='pages'")
private Page page;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="position_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Where(clause="path='users'")
private User user;
```

However this returns all image instances for user or page, disregarding what path it has. Furthermore, when I try to filter the value depending on Image entity's path value, it gives me LazyInitializationException.
How can one go about in solving this problem?